# Virtual URL in angularJs with routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing

I have a list of items app/#/items, and a form to filter the item by the location that it's located in.
I use dirty checking to trigger a method of a service that communicates with the Backend and refreshes the items list within the scope.

Now let's assume that a user thinks his friend might be interested in an item which is located in location A, and he would like to share those search results with his friends, 
but in fact the URL hadn't changed yet, and it's still '/items'.

In Sammy and other frameworks you can create this virtual url easily, how can I do it with angular?.

Comment: Of course I can just redirect the user to a new such as items/:filet, but I'd much rather use 2-way binding, it will be much more effecient for mobiles and tablets